# SQL Server : xml string to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to convert a string to rows using T-SQL. I've found some people using XML for this but I'm running into troubles.

The original record:

A new line seperated string of data

```
New  In Progress  Left Message  On Hold  Researching  Researching (2nd Level)  Researching (3rd Level)  Resolved  Positive  False Positive  Security Respond
```

Using the following statement converts this string into XML:

```
select 
    cast('<i>'+REPLACE(convert(varchar(max), list_items), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),'</i><i>')+'</i>' as xml)
from 
    field
where 
    column_name = 'state' and table_name = 'sv_inquiry'
```

XML string:

```
<i>Unassigned</i><i>Assigned</i><i>Transferred</i><i>Accepted</i><i>Closed</i><i>Reactivated</i>
```

Now I would like to convert every 'i' node into a separate row. I've constructed the query below, but I can't get it working in the way that it returns all the rows...

```
select x.i.value('i[1]', 'varchar(30)')
from (
    select cast('<i>'+REPLACE(convert(varchar(max), list_items), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10),'</i><i>')+'</i>' as xml)
    from field
    where column_name='state' and table_name='sv_inquiry'
) x(i)
```

This will return

```
Unassigned
```

To be clear, when i change 'i[1]' into 'i[2]' it will return 'Assigned'. I've tried '.', this will return the whole string in a single record...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split a string into rows without XML, see for example [the fnSplitString function at SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/).

Here's an example using the [`nodes()` function of the xml type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx).  I'm using a space as the delimiter because SQL Fiddle doesn't play well with line feeds:

```
select  node_column.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
from    (
        select  cast('<i>' + replace(list_items, ' ', '</i><i>') +
                    '</i>' as xml) xml_value
        from    field
        ) f
cross apply
        xml_value.nodes('/i') node_table(node_column);
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10346/8/0)

Answer (score 1):

How about using the [nodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) method on an [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) datatype.

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml = '<i>Unassigned</i><i>Assigned</i><i>Transferred</i><i>Accepted</i><i>Closed</i><i>Reactivated</i>'

select
    t.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as [Word]
from 
    @xml.nodes('/i') as t(c)
```

Comment: Is it possible to put this in one statement. I tried calling the .nodes('/i') after the from, like this from (select ...).nodes('/i') x(i)

Comment: @Bas: You can use `cross apply` for that, example in my answer. +1 for the `nodes()` function which is the central machinery for turning XML into rows.